# Defining types on object creation like HashMap<type here>

Tags: java, object, types

Very simple question, Im implementing a array enumeration class but cannot remember how to get the correct type back on the nextElement() method. The code is as follows...

```
public class ArrayEnumeration<Object> implements Enumeration<Object> {
    private Object[] data;
    private int n = 0;

    public ArrayEnumeration(Object[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return n < data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nextElement() {
        n++;
        return data[n - 1];
    } 
}
```

so object returned from the nextElement method should be the type that was defined when the class was created. I just cannot remember how to do it. So annoying!!!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Enumeration` and doing this for yourself, instead of using the modern collections APIs?

Comment: Which modern api are you referring to? Didn't know any existed for this task. BTW i'm converting my application arguments to use this for arguments like. -appname <appname>.

Comment: Nobody uses `Enumeration` anymore; the typical implementation for what you're doing would be the one-liner `Arrays.asList(array).iterator()`.

Comment: Wish i knew about that an hour ago, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the source code of `java.util.List` for an example:

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/List.java

Your methods then use the generic type:

```
public boolean add(E e);

public E get(int index);
```

All from the source of the `java.util.List`..

So in your case:

```
public class ArrayEnumeration<E> implements Enumeration<E> {

    ...

    @Override
    public E nextElement() {
        n++;
        return data[n - 1];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a type parameter:

```
public class ArrayEnumeration<T>
    implements Enumeration<T> 
{
    private T[] data;

    public ArrayEnumeration(T[] data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    // ...
    public T nextElement() {}
}
```

Also, you should consider using `Iterator` instead. But in any event, arrays implement `Iterable`, so why are you doing this?